# is there a software to download python scripts?

Tags: python, add-on

I want to download and install some add ons and wonder about how to download the python script.
This question is probably stupid but I really don't know the Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add-ons are written in Python. So after downloading your add-on file(s) it will be either a .py file or a .zip file depending on the add-on.

To install it, you go to file->user preferences->add-ons tab->install from file (found at the bottom)->choose your downloaded add-on->then the add-on information will appear after installing it->click the checkbox and the add-on will be active

Comment: Thx for the answer, but my Problem is that I don't know how to download them as a .py file.

Comment: so I Need to install python to download the add ons ? for example the add on list of wiki opens the script but I can't find a Folder or anything to download :/

Comment: @Konradodo when you install Blender it installs python. Could you provide a link of these files you are talking about

Comment: sorry I just recognized ivy gen add on is pre installed since 2.5...(that's a little bit embarassing) thank you anyway.